# Query all nodes with a special attribute value

Tags: attributes, xquery

I have a problem querying an XML structure.

This is the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<LangSet id="1031">
    <field id="Language">1031</field>
    <field id="PrimaryLanguage">7</field>
    <Term id="18">
        <field id="CreatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOn">20060905T170414Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOnUTC">20060905T150414Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOn">20080107T141350Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOnUTC">20080107T121350Z</field>
        <field id="Status">Negativterm.Kunden-orientiert;Negativterm.Technik-orientiert</field>
        <field id="Term">Innenpersenning</field>
        <field id="TermType">MainTerm</field>
        <field id="UpdatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="UpdatedOn">20080107T141350Z</field>
        <field id="UpdatedOnUTC">20080107T121350Z</field>
        <field id="UserId">11817</field>
    </Term>
    <Term id="19">
        <field id="CreatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOn">20020626T120555Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOnUTC">20020626T100555Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOn">20020626T120555Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOnUTC">20020626T100555Z</field>
        <field id="Status">Vorzugsterm.Kunden-orientiert;Vorzugsterm.Technik-orientiert</field>
        <field id="Term">Persenning</field>
        <field id="TermType">MainTerm</field>
        <field id="UserId">18088</field>
    </Term>
    <Term id="20">
        <field id="CreatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOn">20011105T140407Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOnUTC">20011105T120407Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOn">20080107T141350Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOnUTC">20080107T121350Z</field>
        <field id="Status">Negativterm.Kunden-orientiert;Negativterm.Technik-orientiert</field>
        <field id="Term">Verdeckabdeckung</field>
        <field id="TermType">MainTerm</field>
        <field id="UpdatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="UpdatedOn">20080107T141350Z</field>
        <field id="UpdatedOnUTC">20080107T121350Z</field>
        <field id="UserId">32287</field>
    </Term>
</LangSet>
<LangSet id="1031">
    <field id="Language">1031</field>
    <field id="PrimaryLanguage">7</field>
    <Term id="8">
        <field id="CreatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOn">20060905T170414Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOnUTC">20060905T150414Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOn">20070711T153241Z</field>
        <field id="CreatedOrUpdatedOnUTC">20070711T133241Z</field>
        <field id="Status">Vorzugsterm.Kunden-orientiert;Vorzugsterm.Technik-orientiert</field>
        <field id="Term">Innenrad</field>
        <field id="TermType">MainTerm</field>
        <field id="UpdatedBy">dot_Termservice</field>
        <field id="UpdatedOn">20070711T153241Z</field>
        <field id="UpdatedOnUTC">20070711T133241Z</field>
        <field id="UserId">11818</field>
    </Term>
</LangSet>
</document>
```

All I want to do is to get all the Textvalues of the field elements with the attribute id=Term and return them in a LangSet as showned below:

```
    <LangSet> <field id="Term">Innenpersenning</field> <field
    id="Term">Persenning</field> <field id="Term">Verdeckabdeckung</field>
     </LangSet>

     <LangSet>
<field id="Term">Innenrad</field>
</LangSet>

     <LangSet>
<field id="Term">Raumakustik</field>
</LangSet>

     <LangSet> 
<field id="Term">Fahrgastraumbeleuchtung</field> <field
     id="Term">IB</field> <field id="Term">Innenbeleuchtung</field> <field
     id="Term">Innenraumbeleuchtung</field> 
</LangSet>
```

I'm getting the right values but unfortunatley not in a Langset node:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare boundary-space strip;

declare namespace xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
for $x in doc("Sample.xml")/Document/Database/Dictionary/Concept/LangSet/Term//field
where $x/@id="Term"

return $x
```

I'm sure that it isn't that difficult but I'm stuck in documentation and I can't find the solution which works for me.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: There's no `Database/Dictionary/Concept` elements in your input, and `Document` is spell with a lowercase "d". `doc("Sample.xml")/document/LangSet/Term/field` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to return `<LangSet>` elements from your document, which contain appropriate `<field>` descendant elements, they will also contain all their other descendants.

If I understand what you want, you need to create on-the-fly some semi-clone elements reflecting partially your input document filtered and return them.

Scan `LangSet`-s and test each of them for desired descendants. If found, create appropriate output elements:

```
let $doc := doc("Sample.xml")
for $langset in $doc/document/LangSet
let $fields := $langset/descendant::field[@id = 'Term']
where exists($fields)
return
    <LangSet>
    {
        for $field in $fields return
            <field id='Term'>{string($field)}</field>
    }
    </LangSet>
```

Comment: thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!Great! Great!Great!

Comment: @user1788114 Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in our  [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with an top-down approach like [CiaPan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792280/6359607) is or an bottom-up approach.
Based on the xml example you gave solutions could be:

Top-down

```
let $document := doc("langset.xml")/*
for $langset in $document/LangSet
let $fields := $langset//field[@id = 'Term']
return
    <LangSet>
    { $fields }
    </LangSet>
```

Bottom-up

```
let $document := doc("langset.xml")/*
for $field in $document//field[@id = 'Term']
group by $langset := $field/ancestor::LangSet
order by $langset descending
return
    <LangSet>
    { $field }
    </LangSet>
```